# Jenkinsのインストールについて(.msiと.war)の違い

Tags: jenkins

Jenkinsを.msiでインストールすると、他のツールへのキックに失敗します。
.warでインストールすると、同じパイプラインで他のツールへのキックが問題なく動作します。

Jenkinsのバージョン違いとか、Javaのバージョン違いなど、出来る範囲で入れ替えてみたのですが、.msiは失敗、.warは成功という状態から抜け出せません。

最新のJenkinsは.msiで提供されるので、.msiでキックできるようにしたいのですが、.msiと.warでは、インストールフォルダが違う事やフォルダ名が違う事以外にどのような差異があるのでしょうか？

何か、ヒントになることがあれば、是非ご教授ください。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[Jenkins service VS Jenkins .war run](https://www.wedoqa.com/2016/03/jenkins-service-vs-jenkins-war-run/), [What's the difference between running Jenkins using Java and using the windows installer version?](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/573aeg/whats_the_difference_between_running_jenkins/), [Windows上のJenkinsを特定のユーザーで実行する](http://iyemon018.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/25/080000), [スレーブエージェント起動の様々な方法 - Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=55541872)

Comment: Windowsであれば、WinMergeなどの差分比較ツールで両者のインストールディレクトリーを比較してみると、差異が分かります。差異が無いとすれば、msi版はレジストリーに何か書き込んでるかもしれません。